# CBPS Package: PS changes by changing base category

Tags: propensity-scores, mlogit

I am using CBPS package. The treatment variables has three options. Therefore, a multi logit model is run through CBPS. However, the resulting propensity score changes by changing the base category.

An MWE is given below:

```
### Loading Required Libraries 
library(CBPS)
library(stargazer)
library(foreign)
### Loading Data 
sms1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
sms1
attach(sms1)
#Creating Factor Variable 
treatment
treat1 <- factor(treatment,
             levels = c(0,1,2),
             labels = c("None", "SEC", "CB"))

treat2 <- factor(treatment,
             levels = c(2,1,0),
             labels = c("CB", "SEC", "None"))
is.factor(treat1)
is.factor(treat2)
# set of pre-treatment covariates 
Xt_1 <- cbind(RWATA_1, LLPR_1, Size_1, DAR_1, LG_1, CCLR_1, CRLR_1, RMLR_1)
### Model Estimation for ATEs
fit1E <- CBPS(treat1 ~ Xt_1, data = sms1, ATT = 0)
fit1R <- CBPS(treat2 ~ Xt_1, data = sms1, ATT = 0)
sum1E.Just <- summary(fit1E)
sum1R.Just <- summary(fit1R)
#### Model Assessment for Consistency of PS 
v <- cbind(fit1E$fitted.values, fit1R$fitted.values)
v[1:10,]
plot(v[,1],v[,6])
plot(v[,2],v[,5])
plot(v[,3],v[,4])
```

How this issue can be resolved.

Comment: This is not a MWE because we don't have access to the data or the output, so we can't see or reproduce the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your treatment $t_i$ is binary, so units are either in the treated or control condition. You code the control group as the base category, with $t_i=0$, and the treated group with $t_i=1$. Now suppose there is a unit with propensity score $P(t_i=1|x_i)=0.6$. If you flip the coding by giving the controls $t_i=1$ and the treated $t_i=0$ (i.e. if you change the base category), that unit will have a propensity score $P(t_i=1|x_i)=0.4$.